ERR on PATH trying to use npm
I'm just running npm install. Also I cannot run any command involving npm, not even npm update.
I have attempted reinstalling Node.js, changing username on Windows. Adding a global npm directory no success.

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\Users\C:\Users\E5262012CORES\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp'

It is creating this C:\Users\C:\Users\, but I check my path file and there is no such thing as C:\Users\C:\Users\.

I'm on Windows 10

I'm posting this because can be useful to other users:
To change the npm cache directory path, you can use the npm config command with the cache flag. Here's how you can do it:
npm config set cache <new_cache_directory_path>
Replace <new_cache_directory_path> with the desired path where you want npm to store its cache.
For example, if you want to set the cache directory to C:\Users\E5262012CORES\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache, you would run:
npm config set cache C:\Users\E5262012CORES\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Make sure to use the appropriate path for your system. After running this command, npm should start using the new cache directory, and the issue with the path should be resolved.
